next:build:webpack-build Compiler server unexpectedly exited with code: null and signal: SIGKILL +44s
I have connected to cPannel via ssh and when I do npm run build i get the error:
next:build:webpack-build Compiler server unexpectedly exited with code: null and signal: SIGKILL +44s

I tried removing .next and node_modules and reinstalling but it didn't work.
